images from media file wont get displayed in React Native
I want to display the image on my React Native Post.js component but it just showing a white it consume the space of the style I made to the image
settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media' 

models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[
        ('electronics', 'Electronics'),
        ('furniture', 'Furniture'),
        ('clothing', 'Clothing'),
        ('appliances', 'Appliances'),
        ('books', 'Books'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ])
    condition = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[
        ('new', 'New'),
        ('like_new', 'Like New'),
        ('used', 'Used'),
    ])
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_images', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    reserved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reserved_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reserved_items', null=True, blank=True)


    

Post.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import fetchUserData from "../Reusable Component/FetchUserData";
import { COLORS } from "../constants";
import DynamicPostTime from "../Reusable Component/DynamicPostTime";
export default function Post({ listing }) {
  const [userData, setuserData] = useState({
    firstName: "Loading...",
    lastName: "Loading...",
    email: "loading...",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadUserData = async () => {
      setuserData(await fetchUserData());
    };
    loadUserData();
    // console.log(listing.user);
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.post}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Image
          source={{
            uri:
              userData.email === "jieclarkm@gmail.com"
                ? "https://jieclarkdev.github.io/imgs/profile.png"
                : "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjkDmT4fzz9xWxlF77TzA_fCinEC1OKypgPlaphkXU-Q&s",
          }}
          style={styles.profile}
        />

        <View>
          <Text style={styles.name}>
            {userData.firstName} {userData.lastName}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.time}>{DynamicPostTime(listing.created_at)}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.description}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{listing.name}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.description}>{listing.description}</Text>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: listing.image }}
          style={{ aspectRatio: 1, width: "100%" }}
          resizeMode="contain"
          onError={() => console.log("Error display image")}
        />
        {/* <Text>{console.log(listing.image)}</Text> */}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.options}>
        <Text style={[styles.tag, styles.available]}>
          {listing.available === true ? "available" : null}
        </Text>
        <Text style={[styles.tag, styles.category]}>{listing.category}</Text>
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.tag,
            {
              backgroundColor:
                listing.condition === "used"
                  ? COLORS.used
                  : listing.condition === "new"
                  ? COLORS.junkFree
                  : listing.condition === "like_new"
                  ? COLORS.like_new
                  : null,
            },
          ]}
        >
          {listing.condition}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  post: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    margin: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 5,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderRightWidth: 3,
    borderRightColor: COLORS.junkFree,
  },
  header: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  profile: {
    width: 50,
    aspectRatio: 1,
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: COLORS.junkFree,
  },
  description: {
    letterSpacing: 0.3,
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
  },
  time: {
    color: COLORS.darkgray,
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "500",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "600",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: COLORS.transparentBorder,
    paddingBottom: 3,
  },
  options: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    gap: 10,
  },
  tag: {
    fontWeight: "500",
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: COLORS.junkFree,
    borderRadius: 20,
    color: COLORS.lightWhite,
  },

  category: { backgroundColor: COLORS.darkenblue },
});


Profile.js where I render the Post inside the Flatlist
const ProfileScreen = () => {
  const [listing, setListing] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const getUserListings = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

    try {
      const refresh = await authentication.refresh();
      const response = await authentication.userListing();
      dispatch(refreshToken(refresh));
      setListing(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching listings:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onRefresh = () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    getUserListings().then(() => {
      setRefreshing(false);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserListings();
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <FlatList
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={refreshing}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
            colors={[COLORS.junkFree]}
          />
        }
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={listing}
        renderItem={({ item }) => <Post listing={item} />}
        keyExtractor={(listing) => listing.id.toString()}
        ListEmptyComponent={
          isLoading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={COLORS.junkFree} />
          ) : (
            <Text>No Listing Found</Text>
          )
        }
        ListHeaderComponent={ProfileScreenHeader}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#F0F4F8",
        }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ProfileScreen;

I want it to dynamically display the image if the listing.image is not null but it wont please help
To display the image inside the Post.js component

Share example uri (listing.image).
